# TypeError: this._on is not a function

Tags: jquery

How to fix this issue? I have struggled with this issue for more then 4 hours.

> TypeError: this._on is not a function

My Code is there

```
this.input = $( "<input>" )
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .val( value )
      .attr( "title", "" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
      .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
      })
    this._on( this.input, {
      autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
          item: ui.item.option
        });
      },
```

Comment: `_on()` isn't a function in jquery, it should be just `on()`. Some extra context in the form of your code would really help though.

Comment: What code generates this error?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it is on(), not _on().  Also use $(this).on instead of this.on() to ensure it is a jquery object.  If you find yourself doing $(this) alot, store it in a variable to be reused.

Comment: The error message is on 'this._on' not $(this)._on. The problem is he either doesn't have jquery-ui included or it's older than version 1.9.0 which has the '_on' method.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old, Dead thread but for others who come across this as I did looking for why this error is showing up. The answer marked as the correct answer is NOT correct. The questioner is asking about the jquery combobox plugin which is where the code snippet in the question came from. The error is on

```
this._on
```

In this case 'this' refers to the jquery-ui widget object, which as of version 1.9.0 has a method named '_on'. The most likely problem is that the questioner either was not including jquery-ui or was using a version of jquery-ui prior to 1.9.0 that did not have that method. If you get this error, make sure you have jquery-ui loaded and open your jquery-ui file and search for '_on' if you don't find it that is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As Rory mentioned above, this._on() is not a function. Try this.on() i.e. remove the underscore.

You can also look at the link below for correct usage info on on() in jQuery.

[jQuery API on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Now also i faced the same issue, FYI,    `  "TypeError: this.on is not a function
 

this.on( this.input, {" `